# Dual Screen notifications

Tags: 11.10, unity, multiple-monitors, gnome-panel, pidgin

I just finished upgrading from 10.04.3 LTS to 11.10. On 10.04 whenever I got a message on Pidgin or Skype a notification would drop down from the time area with a preview of that message. I am using two screens and it would normally appear on the left screen only. Now on 11.10 the notification appears on my right screen which is mainly meant for my VM. How can I change that drop down bubble to be on the left.

P.S. Is there a way to remove the top panel bar from both screens?

Comment: The part about the top panel appearing up top is by design.

Comment: Ugly design imho. I guess. Oh well I guess Ill get used to it. How about that notifications bubble?

Answer (score 5):

You can make it so that notification bubbles appear on whichever display contains the active window using gconf-editor:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/331369/comments/13

> Considering that multihead support is generally a setup for advanced users, we've also added a gconf key to enable a smarter mode. To enable it, you need to set "/apps/notify-osd/multihead_mode" to "focus-follow".

Comment: When I run gconf-ediotr I dont see an /apps/notify-osd...

Comment: Any other advice?

Comment: Try looking for it in dconf-editor, the gconf-editor key may be deprecated.

Comment: @arukaen: you must be using Ubuntu 11.10 or newer. It uses `dconf` instead of `gconf` as its backend. The last release that used gconf was Maverick or Natty.